# Capitalize "state?"

Tags: geography

Do you capitalize the word "state" when saying, "In Washington State, individuals who are unemployed may apply for treatment through DSHS."

Comment: Capitalize *state* is it stands for the US (I'm returning to the States, or if it's an official title (Secretary of State), when it's part of a nickname (the Nutmeg State) and if it follows the name of the state itself in an institution (Washington State University). It *can* but need not be capitalized following the name of the state otherwise (the landslide in Washington state vs in Washington State - this is about 50-50). So your example is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The state of Washington prefers "[Washington State](http://www.access.wa.gov/topics/environment/)", and New York uses "[New York State](http://www.osc.state.ny.us/)". In informal applications, it's unlikely to be a big deal if you don't capitalize "state". People will almost certainly know what you mean regardless.

Comment: Well, your Washington link doesn't really provide any information (that I could see), and the Department of Transportation in Washington, at least, doesn't prefer "State": https://wsdot.wa.gov/communications/styleguide#:~:text=Do%20not%20capitalize%20state%20in,state%20Transportation%20Department%2C%20state%20funds.